# Log4Net not working for console app

Tags: log4net

I have a console app and I am trying to implement log4Net for it.

I did the following steps -

1. added log4Net reference
2. Created Log4Net.config -

   3. Created the LogHelper.cs class -
   4. Added the following to the AssemblyInfo.cs
      [assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "Log4net.config", Watch = true)]

But the logging doesnt seem to work? Can someone suggest what needs to be done for the logging to work in th console app?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Make sure the config file is set to copy to the output directory.
2. In the [log4net documentation for assembly attributes](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html) it says:

> ".. if you use configuration attributes you must invoke log4net to
>   allow it to read the attributes. A simple call to LogManager.GetLogger
>   will cause the attributes on the **calling assembly**  to be read and
>   processed. **Therefore it is imperative to make a logging call as
>   early as possible during the application start-up, and certainly
>   before any external assemblies have been loaded and invoked.**"

3. If it still doesn't work, enable log4net debugging as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2263359/43846)