# force log4net to overwrite file

Tags: c#, logging, log4net

I develop an application which does something each time in several runs.

I got much logging information in each run. So when a run was successfull (no exceptions thrown), and the users starts a new run, I want to overwrite the log file on starting the new run.

How can I achieve that?

Furthermore: How do I get the log-file name out of the Logger interface? I don't want to parse the `App.xaml.cs`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is:

```
public static void StartNewLogFile()
{
    Hierarchy hierachy = (Hierarchy)log4net.LogManager.GetRepository();
    Logger logger = hierachy.Root;

    var rootAppender = logger.Appenders.OfType<FileAppender>().FirstOrDefault();
    string filename = rootAppender != null ? rootAppender.File : string.Empty;

    while (logger != null)
    {
        foreach (IAppender appender in logger.Appenders)
        {
            FileAppender fileAppender = appender as FileAppender;
            if (fileAppender != null)
            {
                fileAppender.File = filename + "a";
                fileAppender.File = filename;
                fileAppender.ActivateOptions();
            }
        }
        logger = logger.Parent;
    }

    File.Delete(filename + "a");
}
```

With a big help from: [Programatically force a new log file with Log4Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16304810/programatically-force-a-new-log-file-with-log4net?rq=1)

Answer (score 2):

To overwrite the log file, use a [FileAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.FileAppender.html) and set [appendToFile](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.FileAppender.AppendToFile.html) to `false`:

```
appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
    <file value="log.txt" />
    <appendToFile value="false" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] .. etc ..  />
    </layout>
</appender>
```

However this will not be able to know if your run was successful, and will overwrite the file each time the app is run.

Comment: I already have this configuration. The question was, how can I force log4net to overwrite this file at runtime. Not only when the app starts.