# NLog C# config at runtime with different log files

Tags: c#, logging, nlog

My main class is running 10 concurrent threads and I'd like to have the output of each of them in a separate file. Some threads I want to be grouped in the same file. To do this, I've written the following class which generate a `LoggingConfiguration` on the fly. I'd like to generate different `Logger` objects, each with its own specific `LoggingConfiguration`.

Below is my configuration generating method:

```
private LoggingConfiguration GetLoggerConfig(string target)
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(target)){
            Directory.CreateDirectory(target);
        }
        // Step 1. Create configuration object 
        var config = new LoggingConfiguration();

        // Step 2. Create targets and add them to the configuration 
        var consoleTarget = new ColoredConsoleTarget();
        config.AddTarget("console", consoleTarget);

        var fileTarget = new FileTarget();
        config.AddTarget("file", fileTarget);

        var asyncWrapper = new AsyncTargetWrapper();
        asyncWrapper.QueueLimit = 5000;
        asyncWrapper.OverflowAction = AsyncTargetWrapperOverflowAction.Grow;
        asyncWrapper.WrappedTarget = fileTarget;

        // Step 3. Set target properties 
        consoleTarget.Layout = @"${longdate} | ${logger} |  ${level} | ${message}";//@"${date:format=HH\:mm\:ss} ${logger} ${message}";
        fileTarget.FileName = Path.Combine(target, "logs-${shortdate}.txt");
        fileTarget.Layout = "${longdate} | ${machinename} | ${processid} | ${processname} | ${logger} | ${level} | ${message}";

        // Step 4. Define rules
        config.LoggingRules.Add(new LoggingRule("*", LogLevel.Debug, consoleTarget));
        config.LoggingRules.Add(new LoggingRule("*", LogLevel.Debug, asyncWrapper));


        return config;
    }
```

And I'm trying to get to a point where my syntax would look like this:

```
Logger logger1 = GetLoggerConfig(@"C:\Target1");
Logger logger2 = GetLoggerConfig(@"C:\Target2");

logger1.Info("hello -- should be printed in a file");
logger2.Info("World -- should be printed in a different file");
```

Instead what I have is: in each threads I call `LogManager.Configuration = GetLoggerConfig(@"C:\Target1");` and then all the logs from previously initiated threads appear there.

I don't know how many different targets I have before run-time.

Answer (score 1):

NLog only supports ONE `LoggingConfiguration`, so you have to modify the existing at runtime.

One possible solution can be found here:

[C# lock issues when writing to log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43125584/c-sharp-lock-issues-when-writing-to-log/43127141#43127141)

If using NLog 4.5, then you could use the trick with having `${logger}` in the FileTarget-filename. Then you don't need to modify the configuration as runtime, but just create new loggers with the wanted name.

Comment: The problem with what you're suggesting is that I will need to change the configuration everytime I want to write a log message as it will change the global configuration for all other instances of the class running concurrently. Not very good performance-wise I reckon ? It seems ${logger} would output the same name all the time, as each of my instances have the same class name. Another option could be to instantiate different instances of Logger, each non-static, and each having their own configuration ?

Comment: If the same thread uses multiple Loggers and all loggers uses different names, then the use of ${logger} will not work. An alternative solution is to setup a ThreadContext-variable and use that as FileName. `FileName="${mdlc:item=ThreadName}"`. See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/MDLC-Layout-Renderer (Again only works with NLog 4.5)

Comment: Regarding performance of modifying configuration at runtime, then it will probably hurt performance if registering new thread-configurations every second. But if it only happens ones a minute, then you will not see a performance hit. One could consider to cache thread-configurations, and reuse them for other threads after they have been released by old threads. How many threads are you running the same time, maybe just pre-allocate upfront?